# не работает position sticky. не получается застикать favorites__inputs, который должен опускаться к низу секции. Не могу понять, что не так делаю

Tags: html, css

```css
.favorites {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.favorites__inputs {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 82px;
  margin: 0 0 37px -5px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .favorites__inputs {
    z-index: 10500;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #8E8E8E;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 736px) {
  .favorites__inputs {
    column-gap: 50px;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

label {
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 9px;
  align-items: end;
}

.favorites__subtitle {
  color: var(--second-color);
  text-align: start;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 33px;
}

.custom__input {
  display: none;
}

.check__style {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid var(--second-color);
}

.check__style::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background: var(--second-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.text__input {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 5px;
}

.custom__input:checked+.check__style::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.custom__input:checked~.text__input {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.favorites__books {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -110px;
}

.favorite__books_half {
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  padding: 0 110px;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1426px) {
  .favorites__books {
    margin: 0 -70px;
  }
  .favorite__books_half {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
    padding: 0 70px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1340px) {
  .favorites__books {
    margin: 0 -40px;
  }
  .favorite__books_half {
    flex: 0 1 50%;
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  .favorites__books {
    margin: 0 -10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .favorite__books_half {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 40px 0 10px;
    width: 605.875px;
  }
}

.favorite__books_half:nth-child(4n-1),
.favorite__books_half:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  .favorite__books_half:nth-child(3),
  .favorite__books_half:nth-child(7),
  .favorite__books_half:nth-child(11),
  .favorite__books_half:nth-child(15) {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}

.favorites__wrapper_description {
  padding: 13px 0 13px 19px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 550px;
  height: 555px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.description__image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -41px;
}

.favorites__bg_description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.description__subtitle {
  font-family: var(--second-font);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.description__subtitle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: var(--third-color);
}

.description__title {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.description__title>span {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.description__text {
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  max-width: 355px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.description__button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 74px;
  color: var(--first-color);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 9px 23px;
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  outline: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.description__button:hover {
  outline: none;
  background-color: var(--third-color);
  transition: all .4s;
}

.description__button__inactive {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 74px;
  color: var(--third-color);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 9px 23px;
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  border: 1px solid var(--third-color);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

// .favorite__books_half {
//     max-height: 0;
//     opacity: 0;
//     overflow: hidden;
//     transition: max-height 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
//   }
//   .favorite__books_half:not(.invisible) {
//     max-height: 1000px; /* Adjust this value based on your content */
//     opacity: 1;
//   }
// .invisible{
//     display: none;
// }
.favorite__books_half {
  /* Стили блока */
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  display: none;
}

.fade-in {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="favorites" id="Favorites">
  <h2 class="section__title">
    Favorites
  </h2>
  <p class="favorites__subtitle">
    Pick favorites of season
  </p>
  <div class="favorites__inputs">
    <label class="favorite__inputs-tabs">
        <input type="radio" name="num1" class="custom__input" checked >
        <span class="check__style"></span>
        <span class="text__input">Winter</span>
    </label>
    <label class="favorite__inputs-tabs">
        <input type="radio" name="num1" class="custom__input">
        <span class="check__style"></span>
        <span class="text__input">Spring</span>
    </label>
    <label class="favorite__inputs-tabs" data-target="three">
        <input type="radio" name="num1" class="custom__input">
        <span class="check__style"></span>
        <span class="text__input">Summer</span>
    </label>
    <label class="favorite__inputs-tabs">
        <input type="radio" name="num1" class="custom__input">
        <span class="check__style"></span>
        <span class="text__input">Autumn</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="favorites__books">
    <div class="favorite__books_half" data-target="one">
      <div class="favorites__wrapper_description">
        <div class="favorites__bg_description description">
          <h3 class="description__subtitle">
            Staff Picks
          </h3>
          <p class="description__title">
            The Book Eaters <br>
            <span>By Sunyi Dean</span>
          </p>
          <p class="description__text">
            An unusual sci-fi story about a book eater woman who tries desperately to save her dangerous mind-eater son from tradition and certain death. Complete with dysfunctional family values, light Sapphic romance, and a strong, complex protagonist. Not for
            the faint of heart.
          </p>
          <div class="description__image">
            <img src="./images/book.jpg" alt="name of book">
          </div>
          <button class="description__button">
              Buy
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="favorite__books_half" data-target="one">
      <div class="favorites__wrapper_description">
        <div class="favorites__bg_description description">
          <h3 class="description__subtitle">
            Staff Picks
          </h3>
          <p class="description__title">
            Cackle <br>
            <span>By Rachel Harrison</span>
          </p>
          <p class="description__text">
            Are your Halloween movies of choice The Witches of Eastwick and Practical Magic? Look no further than here - where a woman recovering from a breakup moves to a quaint town in upstate New York and befriends a beautiful witch.
          </p>
          <div class="description__image">
            <img src="./images/book(1).jpg" alt="name of book">
          </div>
          <button class="description__button">
              Buy
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="favorite__books_half" data-target="one">
      <div class="favorites__wrapper_description">
        <div class="favorites__bg_description description">
          <h3 class="description__subtitle">
            Staff Picks
          </h3>
          <p class="description__title">
            Dante: Poet of the Secular World <br>
            <span>By Erich Auerbach</span>
          </p>
          <p class="description__text">
            Auerbach's engaging book places the 'Comedy' within the tradition of epic, tragedy, and philosophy in general, arguing for Dante's uniqueness as one who raised the individual and his drama of soul into something of divine significance—an inspired introduction
            to Dante's main themes.
          </p>
          <div class="description__image">
            <img src="./images/book(2).jpg" alt="name of book">
          </div>
          <button class="description__button">
              Buy
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="favorite__books_half" data-target="one">
      <div class="favorites__wrapper_description">
        <div class="favorites__bg_description description">
          <h3 class="description__subtitle">
            Staff Picks
          </h3>
          <p class="description__title">
            The Last Queen <br>
            <span>By Clive Irving</span>
          </p>
          <div class="description__image">
            <img src="./images/book(3).jpg" alt="name of book">
          </div>
          <p class="description__text">
            A timely and revelatory new biography of Queen Elizabeth (and her family) exploring how the Windsors have evolved and thrived as the modern world has changed around them.
          </p>
          <button disabled class="description__button__inactive">
              Own
          </button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```